# HashMap is auto updated when object mutate

Tags: java, scala, hash, hashmap

I have two questions:

1. Why does `HashMap` use the memory address of the key as the identifier
   for the map entry, i.e. bucket. As I understood, as long as I
   override `hashCode()`, the hash code of the key will be use as bucket
   ID instead.
2. Why does `HashMap` get updated when the key mutates as commented in
   the code below:

---

```
object Equals {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val pointX = new Point2(1, 1)
    val pointY = new Point2(2, 1)
    val pointZ = new Point2(4, 4)
    val map = HashMap(pointX -> "X", pointY -> "Y")
    println(s"Map before: $map")
    //Map before: Map(oo.Point2@20 -> X, oo.Point2@3f -> Y)
    pointX.move(3, 3)
    println(s"Map after: $map")
    //Map after: Map(oo.Point2@80 -> X, oo.Point2@3f -> Y)
    println(map(pointZ))
  }
}
class Point2(var x: Int, var y: Int) extends Equals {
  def move(mx: Int, my: Int): Unit = {
    x = x + mx
    y = y + my
  }
  override def hashCode(): Int = y + (31 * x)
  def canEqual(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
    case p: Point2 => true
    case _ => false
  }
  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = {
    def strictEquals(other: Point2) =
    this.x == other.x && this.y == other.y
      that match {
        case a: AnyRef if this eq a => true
        case p: Point2 => (p canEqual this) && strictEquals(p)
        case _ => false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not just HashMap.. this is how java works.. that too for some reason.. make your class immutable if you want it so..

Answer (score 7):

> Why does HashMap use the memory address of the key as the identifier for the map entry

It doesn't. It uses the hash code of the key. (Why do you think it uses the memory address?).

If you're wondering why the key looks like `oo.Point2@20`, that's because you didn't override `toString()` in class `Point`.

> Why does HashMap get updated when the key mutates

Because `HashMap` does not make a copy of the objects that you use as keys; it just stores a reference to the key object. If you modify the key after putting it in the `HashMap`, then the `HashMap` will also see the change.

This will mess up your `HashMap` if the key object changes in such a way that its `hashCode()` method would return a different value (because the entry might suddenly be in the wrong bucket).

Do not modify objects that you use as keys in a `HashMap`, because that will cause strange problems (it might look like the object disappears from the map, for example). Objects that you use as keys in a `HashMap` should be immutable.

Comment: Actually requiring the key to be immutable is too strict. Requiring the *identity* of the key to not change should suffice. Good answer, anyways.

Comment: If only identity of the keys matters `IdentityHashMap` would be a good choice. Then you can freely mutate your keys.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner To my understanding the reference value *is* the identity of an object. Think of indentity as a *synonym* of reference value, then the name makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Durandal OK, I understand your point. I meant *identity* regarding the `equals()` contract, i.e. if you have a `Person` object with `socialSecurityNumber`, `name` and `lastName` fields, the identity regarding `equals()` would be defined only by the `socialSecurityNumber` field, since it's unique among all people. But actually, that's *equality* and not identity. My bad.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner *Because HashMap does not make a copy of the objects that you use as keys; it just stores a reference to the key object.* -> What do you mean by reference? I thought the HashMap is a set of buckets in which each bucket is a linked list of pairs, such as [(hashCode(pointX), "X"), (hashCode(pointZ), "Z")] since both pointX and pointZ have the same hashCode.

Comment: @LuongBaLinh The pairs do not store only the hash code of the key; that would not be sufficient. Note that different objects may have the same hash code (hash codes are not unique!). A bucket contains the pairs where the keys have the same hash code; a bucket may contain multiple pairs. To distinguish them, the `HashMap` calls `equals` on the keys.

Comment: @Jesper Yes, I know it. I mentioned *I thought the HashMap is a set of buckets in which each bucket is a linked list of pairs*. Is it what you mean?

Comment: @LuongBaLinh A bucket is more like a linked list of pairs: [(key1, value1), (key2, value2), ...] instead of [(hashCode(key1), value1), (hashCode(key2), value2), ...]